# Alfresco Share Aikau PathTree to show documents not just folders

Tags: dojo, alfresco, alfresco-share, aikau

I am working on an Aikau Share Page where I a side bar that is using the Alfresco Share document library tree picker. The picker allows me to publish the nodeRef to another widget which will display information. I would like to use the tree view but i'm having trouble showing the documents and it is only showing the containers/folders. Anyone have any idea on what I need to do in order to solve this?

Here is the Aikua code i am using:

```
{
        align: "sidebar",
        name: "alfresco/layout/Twister",
        config: {
         label: "twister.library.label",
         additionalCssClasses: "no-borders",
         widgets: [
                {
                    name: "alfresco/navigation/PathTree",
                    config: {
                       showRoot: true,
                       rootLabel: "Repository",
                       rootNode: "/app:company_home",
                       publishTopic: "ALF_ITEM_SELECTED"
                    }
                    }                       
                ]
            }   
}
```

I am wondering if I need to write an extension to the CoreXhr or what the steps would be in order to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. The problem comes from the repository script in the alfresco explorer side "treenode.get.js". The solution was to do the following

1. Create a new webscript in alfresco explorer and copy treenode.get.js code into the new webscript. I ended up calling mine customtreenode.get.js.
2. Remove the logic check for IsContainer in the newly created webscript
3. Create new Aikau file that extends PathTree. Here is the code below

   ```
       define(["dojo/_base/declare",
       "alfresco/navigation/PathTree",
       "alfresco/documentlibrary/_AlfDocumentListTopicMixin",
       "service/constants/Default",
       "dojo/_base/lang",
       "dojo/_base/array",
       "dojo/dom-class",
       "dojo/query",
       "dojo/NodeList-dom"], 
       function(declare, PathTree, _AlfDocumentListTopicMixin, AlfConstants, lang, array, domClass, query) {

       return declare([PathTree, _AlfDocumentListTopicMixin], {

               useHash: true,

                getTargetUrl: function alfresco_navigation_Tree__getTargetUrl() {
                    var url = null;
                    if (this.siteId && this.containerId)
                    {
                       url = AlfConstants.PROXY_URI + "slingshot/doclib/treenodeCustom/site/" + this.siteId + "/documentlibrary";
                    }
                    else if (this.rootNode)
                    {
                       url = AlfConstants.PROXY_URI + "slingshot/doclib/treenodeCustom/node/alfresco/company/home";
                    }
                    else if (!this.childRequestPublishTopic)
                    {
                       this.alfLog("error", "Cannot create a tree without 'siteId' and 'containerId' or 'rootNode' attributes", this);
                    }
                    return url;
                }
       });
    });
   ```
4. Change your code to use the new CustomPathTree

   ```
       {
       align: "sidebar",
       name: "alfresco/layout/Twister",
       config: {
        label: "twister.library.label",
        additionalCssClasses: "no-borders",
        widgets: [
               {
                   name: "CustomWidgets/widgets/CustomTreeNode",
                   config: {
                      showRoot: true,
                      rootLabel: "Repository",
                      rootNode: "/app:company_home",
                      publishTopic: "ALF_ITEM_SELECTED"
                     }
                   }
               ]
           }   
   }
   ```

It works after that. I still need to change the icons from folders to documents.

Comment: This is an interesting use case that the Aikau team hasn't come across... it might be worth you raising this as a feature request at issues.alfresco.com or on GitHub (https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/issues) and we could look at enhancing the existing behaviour or providing an alternative widget.